# How to create a dictionary with an array linking to a keyword

Tags: python, dictionary

So basically i need to create a dictionary (or other data structure similar) in which i give an array as one parameter and it maps it to a key word. One example of this could be if you have an array

```
a=['Ohio','California','Colorado']
```

and

```
b=['Los Angeles','San Diego','Denver']
```

Real example:

```
data['OCC_Desc'] = ['Oncology','Market_ana','67W045','Fret678',etc..]
data['LoB'] = ['7856op','Ran0p','Mkl45',etc..]
```

parameter:

```
param['column_name']=['OCC_Desc','LoB','OCC',etc..]
param['parameter'] = ['Oncology','7856op','Fret678',etc...]
param['Offering'] = ['Medicine','Transport','Supplies',etc...]
```

and the output if i used this "dictionary" would be in this brief example

```
data['Offering'] = ['Medicine','Transport']
```

Example of the structure of the dataframe for the parameters

```py
  Column      Parameter     Offering
0  Location   Los Angeles    City 
1  Team       Los Angeles    Lakers
2  Location   Colorado        State
3  Food        Italy         Pizza
4  Location    Germany        Country
```

you will link 'a' to the string 'State' and 'b' to the string 'City'. So later on when i implement it on a dataframe i can give a column for input and this "dictionary" will check each row of the dataframe into this arrays and return either 'City' or 'State'.

The example above is just for understanding the problem, in reality i have to do this to a dataset for school and i have the parameters for multiple columns linking to multiple categories (14 columns that act as parameters and 16 different categories as result, which this categories can be the result from multiple parameters [literally hundreds] and from different columns)

Comment: can't you put the elements in `a` and `b` as key, and 'City' or 'State' as value? in return you get a dict `d = {'Ohio': 'State', 'California': 'State', 'Colorado': 'State', 'Los Angeles': 'City', 'San Diego': 'City', 'Denver': 'City'}`

Comment: Yeah, thats the solution i thought of. But now imagine theres one more "dimension" to this issue. You want a dictionary that is able to identify "categories" to return an answer depending on which column of the dataframe is located the key. So for example if you have "Los Angeles" under the column "Location" it will return "city" but if you have "Los Angeles" under the column "Team" it will return "Lakers".

Comment: Basically you have to give sample data of your real problem, the example you gave is not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas

a = ['Ohio','California','Colorado']
b = ['Los Angeles','San Diego','Denver']

param_dict = {
    'State':a,
    'City':b}

df_dict = {
    'x':['Ohio','ToothBrush','San Diego'],
    'y':['Colorado','Hammer','Denver'],
    'z':['California','Gun','Los Angeles']}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data = df_dict)
print(df) 

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    row = row[:]
    if set(param_dict.get('State')).issubset(set(row)):
        print(f"Row {list(row)} at index {index} is a State")
    if set(param_dict.get('City')).issubset(set(row)):
        print(f"Row {list(row)} at index {index} is a City")
```

OUTPUT

```
            x         y            z
0        Ohio  Colorado   California
1  ToothBrush    Hammer          Gun
2   San Diego    Denver  Los Angeles

Row ['Ohio', 'Colorado', 'California'] at index 0 is a State
Row ['San Diego', 'Denver', 'Los Angeles'] at index 2 is a City
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question, it really means a lot to me. Regarding the solution you suggested, its not quite what im looking for. I've tried to solve the problem by other manners. My first guess was trying to make a dictionary, where there is an array (like the ones i mentioned above) and that given array is linked to a 'key word'. So when i implemented this dictionary to a dataframe, it will iterate through each row of a certain column of the dataframe and if it found one element from the array, then it will return the 'key word' i linked it to.

Comment: The real problem is that i have a dataset which contains 14 different columns, and about 1000 rows. I was given a list of parameters in the shape of "IF a THEN b" where the parameters can give a total of 16 different "Offering" categories, I have multiple parameters for each  column of the dataset, and the results of those parameters may lead to one of the 16 different "Offering" categories. So i need to somehow, make a data type where i can organize all the parameters that share the same IF (which is the column of the dataset i need to analyze) and link each parameter to the"Offering" categry

Comment: So in total i will have 14 columns of parameters (could be seen as 14 dictionaries) and then i could implement it to the dataset

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I am happy to help. So, you have a pandas.DataFrame of 14 columns with many rows. Where are these parameters stored? Are they inside your DataFrame or are they a separate list? Also, can you provide one example of a column, an element in that column, two parameters for that column, and a category those parameters belong to. This would help me to get you a different solution.

Comment: @GuillermoCampollo Please look at the question I added onto the end of my answer. Also, you say each IF is one of the columns, what is each THEN?

Comment: I added a easy to see example of the parameter data frame to the original question, thanks a lot again

Comment: @GuillermoCampollo Check out the new answer. Is this a _little_ close to what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yeah it did helped me figuring out the solution, I ended up making a dictionary of dictionaries, where the first keys where the column  names of the dataset and those keys had as values dictionaries with hundreds of parameters and values to them.

Comment: @GuillermoCampollo Sounds good, happy I could help you. If there is anything else you need or want to know just comment. Have a nice day.